# How to get audio from Amazon Lex response using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-lex

I have an Amazon Lex instance setup in AWS.

I can communicate with it using the python library `boto3`

I can successfully get and send responses using the `client.post_text()` command as well as the `client.post_content()`

I can see that there is a `audioStream` object which is of type `StreamingBody` attached to the response, but I seem to have no way to play that stream. I have tried:

```
audio = response['audioStream']
audio.read()
```

but this seems to have no effect. There is very little documentation describing how to use this object.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found is the following, using `pygame` to parse the audio:

I get the response from Lex and parse it out to find the audio stream, and then play it.

```
Stream = response["audioStream"]

os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"
pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((1,1))
pygame.mixer.music.load(Stream)
pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
clock.tick(10)
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.event.poll()
    clock.tick(10)
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
return
```

Note: I set the video driver to "dummy" so I can run this on my device over `ssh`. Otherwise pygame requires an Xserver instance (its main use is to run a game after all). It also will not run in the background (a `screen` instance for example) if you're running Lex on something headless

Answer (score 0):

I believe the audioStream object is an mpeg / audio encoded blob, so you would need a python library that can play an mp3.

Comment: Can you give me an example with a library?